# Can I bulk register contributors for a new blog

Tags: users, user-registration

I just designed a blog to go with our small classic car club website here in the south of Spain. Before I make it available to club members I need to do something about registration. I have read up on as much as I can find but couldn't find an answer to this:

Ideally I would like to be able to pre-register the 60 or so members so that they can post and comment from the outset (some are not very computer literate and registering first might throw them for a loop).

I have looked at the user creation part of Dashboard and it would be very laborious to have to do this for every member. Is there a simple way to create, say, contributor rights for all the members?

I have their names and email addresses - e.g. in an excel file. Is there any way to cut and paste from, or import a pre-defined list?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: not sure if your looking for a paid or free plunging but this ugin by [wpmudev batch create](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/batch-create) will low you to upload a file full of users

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin that will help you import mass numbers from a .csv - [CSV User Import](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-user-import/)

Just be sure to setup your excel file with the fields in the right order and save as .csv

Comment: Thats what it was called i was looking and looking and i thought there was a free version but i could only find the wpmudev one. I would do this if you want free although i have used the wpmudev one before and its nice.